# Weird block of div just outside viewport in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

First off, please excuse my English as it is not my first language.

I have encountered a very weird issue in an online store I am working on. It only happens in Chrome and I simply couldn't figure out what's going on and it's driving me crazy :(

This is the website I am talking about: 
heavenlynature.co.nz

To replicate the issue (please bear with me), you need to add a couple of individual items to the shopping cart (at least 2 different items, then click the shopping cart icon (heavenlynature.co.nz/cart), shrink the browser viewport just below the first line of item, like the image below:

http://francisthedesigner.co.nz/images/test/2.png

Then drag the scroll bar downwards, you will find a block of div blocking over the top of the text/image (please try refreshing until the issue appears as sometimes it appears to be loading correctly), like the image below:

http://francisthedesigner.co.nz/images/test/3.png

But as soon as you highlight the page or hover over the div it just disappears. Now this only happens in Chrome and Firefox doesn't seem to replicate this issue.

It seems to happen only in the checkout screens, really losing it trying to make this work, any help will be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately even after following your instructions i couldn't replicate your issue. Can you please try to go on your Chrome under Tools/Extensions and disable them all?
Can you also try to replicate this issue from an other computer?

Comment: Please do try refresh a couple time while you're on the checkout page, as doesn't not happen every single time.

Comment: Even I tried from my side. But couldn't replicate it. It is showing buttons and price properly. Could you please right click on the bottom overlapping div/image and select "Inspect Element"? This will reveal what exactly it is in the Chrome Developer Tools. Also share that screen with us if you have any issues.

Comment: Have tested it from 3 different environments and simply can't replicate this issue. It must be related with the specific environment of the OP.

Comment: Right, thanks for trying to replicate the issue. I am on a Mac OS X version 10.8.3, Chrome Version 28.0.1500.95. I cannot find anything under development tool, and what makes it harder to inspect is the div block dissapear when its tempered ie. highlights/hovered etc. And it only happens whenever its outside the viewport, so if you adjust the viewport and refresh again, the div will adjust the position itself and can only be revealed once you start dragging down the scrollbar. I will try find a different machine tonight and report back.